# Use %20 instead of + in URL after submitting form with GET method in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, forms

Below is code of form in PHP. Submitting this form shows + sign instead of %20, in url for space.

```
<form id="search" action="/search" method="get" novalidate="">
    <input type="text" id="search-value" name="query">
    <button type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

When I search for Hello World, it should show Hello%20World in URL, not Hello+World

Comment: `+` is the standard way to encode spaces in submitted form data, and is supported by all standard libraries for handling query strings. Why do you want to avoid normal behaviour? (You might have a good reason, but this smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Agreed, why does it matter? It's not a bug.

Comment: If it's a problem for you, you can observe the submit button with javascript and use encodeURI function before send the form

Comment: graphizy.com here we have that issue while www.freepik.com is using %20

Comment: It really doesn't matter, it's not an issue.  Both versions are acceptable.

Comment: Yes but is there anyway to change it?

Comment: Well someone just suggested that above in an earlier comment...but why do you care? Spend your energy on something which will actually improve your application

Comment: Is this an actual issue right now with some part of your code? If yes, then please add that code and explain, in detail, what the code suppose to do and what currently happens. I don't see where this would/should be an issue. If there isn't an actual problem right now and you're just expecting it to be an issue, then try it first and come back when you have something concrete.